# Installed Wordpress.com Stats with api key and forgot key. How can I register w/ new key?

Tags: plugins

I tried deleting the plugin, reinstalling, and entering a new api key. However, I get this message:

> The owner of that API Key (username)
>   is not on the access list for this
>   blog (blog id). Stats was installed
>   using a different API key.

Is there anyway I can install the Wordpress.com Stats plugin with a new api key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should be using the [JetPack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) plugin now, not the stats plugin.  Automattic (the team behind WordPress.com) have begun bundling their stats system with a few other features (social network sharing, LaTeX support, to name a couple) and [aren't updating the older systems any more](http://jetpack.me/faq/).

JetPack will use oAuth to connect to your WordPress.com account and will automatically select the right blog.  If it doesn't, you should [contact their support team](http://en.support.wordpress.com/) directly to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging into your wordpress.com account, and grabbing your existing API key?